# Twitter v1.1 updated, but we still do not get a response from the new API

Tags: c#, twitter

Twitter has deprecated their V1 api, so we created an application on Twitter, updated our web config with the new AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret, consumerKey and consumerSecret.

But we are not really getting any response back from the new API though, 
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/themarilynshow

The old api URL is
https://api.twitter.com/1/themarilynshow

and that is OK,

Any ideas why? or which steps i missed?

Comment: They deprecated their v1.0 API a while back now. It was *retired* on 11th June 2013 ;)

Comment: Also, **what language are you using?**

Comment: C#, we use TweetSharp as a 3rd party library. It is still making calls to api.twitter.com/1/ , which is deprecated. That is why. I am looking to see if there are new TweetSharp library that supports api 1.1

Answer (score 0):

You just need to login to your twitter developer's account by opening the link https://twitter.com/settings/widgets and create new widget. Choose user timeline if you need to show the tweets on your website. After you have added all the specification a code is generated. For example:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" data-widget-id="YOUR-WIDGET-ID-HERE">Tweets by @twitterapi</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Comment: but the thing is I am using TweetSharp as a 3rd party library. And I debugged it , it is still making calls to api.twitter.com/1/